# Regex select text outside two strings and .replace on the selection

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like the following:

```
"This is a test [Text that (cannot) be changed]. But (this) can be changed."
```

I want to replace the strings inside `(` and `)` with html but not when they are inside `[ ]`. I want to replace all text within `[ ]` with a different html. My final result would look like the following.

```
"This is a test <p>Text that (cannot) be changed</p>". But <b>this</b> can be changed."
```

I created an expression that could select everything outside the `[ ]` strings. But how can I perform replace to this selected text only? To select everything outside `[ ]` I use this:

```
([^\[\]]+)(?:\s|$|\[)
```

This selects all text outside `[` and `]`. I want to perform regex replace for `( )` on this selected text only.

Comment: Do you always want to replace `[...]` by `<p>...</p>`, and `(...)` by `<b>...</b>`? (Except when `(...)` is inside `[...]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach here is explained in **[this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23589204/2684660)** where you use a `don't catch this|(do catch this)` technique. My regex is this:

```
\[[^\]]*]|\(([^)]*)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/BbsQR2V2S2DSip5M)

So I catch everything between `[]` as well as everything between `()`, but only the latter generates a capture-group with the text you wanna keep. I can then examine this capture-group to decide what to do: return it unchanged or put `<b></b>` around it.

```js
var subject = 'This (is) a test [Then some text that (cannot) (be) changed]. But (this) can (be) changed.';
var regex = /\[[^\]]*]|\(([^)]*)\)/g;

var replace = subject.replace(regex, function(match, p1)
{
    return (p1==undefined)?match:'<b>'+p1+'</b>';
});

console.log(replace);
// This <b>is</b> a test [Then some text that (cannot) (be) changed]. But <b>this</b> can <b>be</b> changed.
```

*(credit to @johansatge for the nice template, I just changed the regex and the `return` line)*

Answer (score 2):

You might combine a regex and a callback function to replace the stuff you want:

```
var subject = 'This (is) a test [Then some text that (cannot) (be) changed]. But (this) (can) be changed.';
var regex = /(?:^|])([^\[]*)(?:\n|$|\[)/g;

var replace = subject.replace(regex, function(match, p1)
{
    return match.replace(/\(/g, '<b>').replace(/\)/g, '</b>');
});

console.log(replace);
// This <b>is</b> a test [Then some text that (cannot) (be) changed]. But <b>this</b> <b>can</b> be changed.
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q21sns3s/2/

Regex explanation:

`(?:^|])`: we need the beginning of the subject or a closing `]`

`([^\[]*)`: followed by anything but an opening `[`

`(?:\n|$|\[)`: ended by an opening `[`, a new line or the end of the subject (`$`)

Comment: Good method. Only drawback to this is that it could lead to open tags. For example if your text is `var subject = 'This (is) a test [Then some text that (cannot) (be) changed]. But (this) (can be changed.';`. Notice the unclosed bracket on the last `can`. This leads to <b> not being ended with </b>

Answer (score 0):

Using `/[(][a-z]+[)]/g` on the text you have extracted will allow you to replace the text `"(this)"`

```
var newText = myExtractedText.replace(/[(][a-z]+[)]/g, "(new text)");
```

EDIT:

To replace the text from the string initially (With out extracting the stuff inside the '[]' first, you can do:

```
var s = "This is a test [Text that (cannot) be changed]. But (this) can be changed.",
    match = s.match(/[a-z ]+([(][a-z]+[)])[a-z .]+$/ig)[0];

console.log(match.replace(/[(][a-z]+[)]/, '(new text)'));
```

Comment: This modifies the `(cannot)` text too.

Comment: @Rawing in the OP "I created an expression that could select everything outside the [ ] strings" so he has already extracted the text containing the area he wants to change ('myExtractedText')

Comment: It hasn't been extracted. The regex I put up simply selects the part of the text that is outside `[` and `]`. If you really do extract this you will get an array of matches, which is still difficult to be evaluated into a complete string i.e. `"This is a test <p>Text that (cannot) be changed</p>". But <b>this</b> can be changed."`

Comment: updated the answer to add the initial part (ignoring the brackets in side the square brackets)

Answer (score 0):

You could do sth. like this to capture only (..) which are not inside []. But Javascript lacks the lookbehind feature.

```
(?!\[)\(.*?\)(?<!\])
```

You could mimic this feature like described in [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-lookbehind). However it think the answer of @funkwurm seem's much cleaner. It's the best way to go for a problem like this.